# Angular - How to do code-splitting in Angular 9 - Ivy?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, code-splitting

In Angular 8 (`8.2.14`), my app can do code splitting by lazy loaded modules.
The build logs is as follows (some redundant lines is omitted), 36 chunks:

```
chunk {3} runtime-es2015.c423f91aaae76527df5b.js (runtime) 3.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {3} runtime-es5.c423f91aaae76527df5b.js (runtime) 3.07 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {2} 2-es2015.539ede95a6745ef5d2bf.js () 22.6 kB  [rendered]
...
chunk {12} polyfills-es2015.32f951d8d1908f922bdc.js (polyfills) 35.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {10} 10-es2015.8da7355d1a7b512401a1.js () 31.7 kB  [rendered]
...
chunk {0} 0-es5.bfd951267cfba9ec1f8d.js () 32.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} common-es2015.10ba6f24dba298440ecc.js (common) 13.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} common-es5.10ba6f24dba298440ecc.js (common) 19.6 kB  [rendered]
...
chunk {11} main-es2015.29e5558ae4fba71b1763.js (main) 755 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {11} main-es5.29e5558ae4fba71b1763.js (main) 806 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {36} 36-es2015.f988ae90643f26871ae8.js () 231 kB  [rendered]
...
chunk {15} vendor-es5.e7af4362172dcd47c55b.js (vendor) 1.41 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {14} styles.5ab582a2e3cd140ea795.css (styles) 301 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

After upgraded to Angular 9 (`9.1.12`), using `ng update` (`ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9`).

The app run fine but the production build consist of several big bundles, build logs as follows, 6 chunks:

```
chunk {0} runtime-es2015.602346de10cd8007336b.js (runtime) 2.25 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es5.602346de10cd8007336b.js (runtime) 2.25 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es2015.b2b33e7ed47c34d70569.js (polyfills) 37.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main-main-module-es2015.f40c22576bd3c677d2bf.js (main-main-module) 1.63 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} main-main-module-es5.f40c22576bd3c677d2bf.js (main-main-module) 3.24 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} polyfills-es5.9fc110dc43c419da899c.js (polyfills-es5) 130 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es2015.49ac9fca75e556a35c57.js (main) 1.45 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es5.49ac9fca75e556a35c57.js (main) 1.54 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {6} vendor-es2015.b8aa44d253e8fc5e1203.js (vendor) 2.28 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {6} vendor-es5.b8aa44d253e8fc5e1203.js (vendor) 2.44 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} styles.03960512702293db9549.css (styles) 288 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

So, how to do code-splitting on lazy loaded modules in Angular 9, Ivy renderer?

Notes:

- The upgrade is ran automatically by `ng update`, no manual fixes.
- All `loadChildren` is changed to new syntax:

  ```
  loadChildren: () => import('../authentication/authentication.module').then((m) => m.AuthenticationModule),
  ```
- The relevant `angular.json` configs is here:

  ```
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "apps/web-web/src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "apps/web-web/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": true,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
        },
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb",
          "maximumError": "10kb"
        }
      ],
      "serviceWorker": true,
      "ngswConfigPath": "apps/web-web/ngsw-config.json"
    }
  }
  ```
- This a project inside a [Nx](https://nx.dev/angular) workspace with [xplat](https://nstudio.io/xplat/).
- We don't want to upgrade to Angular 10 now, as we are sharing code with a Nativescript Angular project, and want to wait until Nativescript works well with Angular 10.
- Typescript configs:

  ```
  // tsconfig.json
  {
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "rootDir": ".",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "importHelpers": true,
      "target": "es2015",
      "module": "esnext",
      "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
      "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@workspacename/*": ["libs/*"],
        "@workspacename/nativescript": ["xplat/nativescript/index.ts"],
        "@workspacename/nativescript/*": ["xplat/nativescript/*"],
        "@workspacename/web": ["xplat/web/index.ts"],
        "@workspacename/web/*": ["xplat/web/*"],
        "core-js/es7/reflect": ["node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"],
        "core-js/es6/*": ["node_modules/core-js/es/*"]
      }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
  }

  // apps/project-name/tsconfig.json
  {
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "types": ["node", "jest"]
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
  }

  // apps/project-name/tsconfig.app.json
  {
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
      "types": []
    },
    "files": [
      "src/main.ts",
      "src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
      "**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "src/test-setup.ts",
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      "**/*.stories.ts"
    ]
  }
  ```

Comment: could you please add your tsconfig to the question?

Comment: Have you already read [this article](https://web.dev/route-level-code-splitting-in-angular/)? You can run `ng g module nyan --module app --route nyan`. It generates a module for your page, and you only load the modules you actually need for your page, inside this dedicated module.

Comment: Hi @Steve, I've added the `tsconfig` files in the question.

Comment: Hi @Pieterjan, I read that article already but it doesn't help. Please note that the app's code splitting is already working since Angular 6 through 7 and 8, it just stop working when I upgraded to Angular 9.

Comment: That's definitely odd. I haven't looked after the module size till now but i'll try tto look at it

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not importing your lazy (child) modules into app.module.

(wrong)

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { CustomersModule } from './customers/customers.module';
import { OrdersModule } from './orders/orders.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CustomersModule,
    OrdersModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

(right)

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

(both wrong and right code above uses this routing file:)

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'customers', loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule) },
  { path: 'orders', loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule) }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```